# how can I transfer my data input in angular http post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to comsume my web service without php. With Angular how can I execute an web service with input param of a form. It'a REST configuration. And I tried my query with POSTMAN

```
mY WEB PAGE : 


----------------------------------------------------------------------------


 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title>connexion.html</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    </head>

    <form ng-submit ng-controller="valController" data-action="http://localhost:8080/globalAlfWs/cxf/user/login">

        <input type="text" name="login" ng-model="login">
        <input type="text" name="password" ng-model="password">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
</html>
```

---

//MY CONTROLLER with the web service link :

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);
   app.controller('valController',function($scope, $http){
        $scope.submit = function(){
            $http({
              method:'POST',
                                   url:"http://localhost:8080/globalAlfWs/cxf/user/login",
                                        data : {
                                            login: $scope.login,
                                            password: $scope.password
                                        },
                                        headers: {
                                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                        }
                                    })
                                            .success(function(response){
                                                $scope.result = response;
                                                console.log(result);
                                            })
                                            .error(function(){
                                                console.log("error");
                                            });
                                };
                            });
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is my result with POSTMAN :

{
  "results": {
    "sessionId": "TICKET_9aee7b3f48fc12e558e6f56b1ede1aea0428cf78",
    "success": true,
    "userName": "login"
  }
}
```

My js fiddle :
[code](http://jsfiddle.net/kakame/u4daa089/5/)

EDIT /

```
var appel = angular.module("appel",[]);
```

appel.controller('ValController',function($scope, $http){

```
    var data = new FormData;

    $scope.submit = function(){
        data.append("login",$scope.login);
        data.append("password",$scope.password);
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:"http://localhost:8080/globalAlfWs/cxf/user/login",
            data : data,
           headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        })
            .success(function(response){
                $scope.result = response;
                console.log($scope.result);
            })
            .error(function(){
                console.log("error");
            });
    };
});
```

It works !!

Comment: you need an `ng-click` to call submit.

Comment: Please make fiddle and plunker and give more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, you were missing the call to your submit function on ngSubmit:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title>connexion.html</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    </head>

    <form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="valController">

        <input type="text" name="login" ng-model="login">
        <input type="text" name="password" ng-model="password">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
</html>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.submit = function(){
        var data = new FormData;
        data.append("login", $scope.login);
        data.append("password", $scope.password);
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:"http://localhost:8080/globalAlfWs/cxf/user/login",
            data : data,
           headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        })
            .success(function(response){
                $scope.result = response;
                console.log($scope.result);
            })
            .error(function(){
                console.log("error");
            });
    };
});
```

Let me know if you get any more issues.

Comment: is it actually stepping into the submit function?

Comment: I added my js fiddle, and yes is it in the submit function

Comment: the web service return me a json response I want this response even if the params are wrong or does not exist ^^

Comment: the web service make request in the network tab, yes

Comment: and what is the response?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the `data-action` attribute if you are using the `submit` button and `submit` action on the form. Otherwise the submit button triggers a form submit on the action URL and your ajax request doesn't work.

Here's the modifications I made to your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4daa089/6/) and it works on the Mock URL I have used.

```
<form ng-submit ng-controller="valController" >
```

```js
   $scope.submit = function(){
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:"http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
            data : {
                login: $scope.login,
                password: $scope.password
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .success(function(response){
                $scope.result = response;
                console.log($scope.result);
            })
            .error(function(){
                console.log("error");
            });
    };
```

Comment: HTTP Error 415 Unsupported media type because of the "Content-type". I don't understand why...

Comment: Looks like your server doesn't accept JSON data for this request. What server are you using, and is your request parser set up to support JSON?

Comment: I'm using TomCat server. But when I change param of content for 'undefined' it works....